# Why does CAN dominant signals override recessive signals?

Tags: voltage, can

I am studying how the CAN standard works and I am unsure how the voltage works in the system. I know that a recessive signal is a 1 and is represented in a 5V configuration by ~2.5V where the voltage difference is close to 0. The dominant signal is a 0 and is represented by ~3.5V on CAN high and ~1.5V on CAN low where the voltage difference is ~0.9V. Where does the voltage come from for these signals? Do all the nodes send the voltage but would that not result in a high voltage? If a dominant signal and recessive signal are sent at the same time by different nodes would that not result in an unreadable signal even though the dominant signal will override the recessive?

Comment: Those voltages you listed as logic THRESHOLDS, not the voltage applied to the line. Voltage sources are not the only thing that can be applied to a line. Do you know how pull-up or pull-down resistors works? Now instead of resistors, imagine them as pull-up or pull-down current sources. You might be in over your head if you do not understand these terms. Look at how I2C works first. It's simpler to understand.

Comment: "If a dominant signal and recessive signal are sent at the same time by different nodes"  and here lies your problem. The nodes do not "send" recessive signals, only dominant. The bus goes into recessive state by itself (thanks to resistors) when no dominant signals present.

Answer (score 1):

At the hardware level, "sending a 0" means shorting it to ground.  The "1" is provided by a resistor that's connected to the supply voltage.  Only when nothing is trying to assert a 0 will the voltage be high.  When it is low, current flows through the resistor, but the voltage at the grounded end hardly changes.

Anything bring the signal low always "wins" against the resistor.  This is why they call it dominant.  The "recessive" 1 only shows up if all the dominants go away.

Note that the voltage spec includes words like "min" and "max".  For example, "Low = 1.5v max" means that anything 1.5v or less will be read as Low.  This is the purpose of "digital" logic.  It tolerates variations in voltage like that.

Comment: This is not true for CAN bus signals.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to know is that CAN is differential; the bus has 2 signals: CAN High and CAN Low. The state of the bus is determined by the voltage difference V(CAN High) - V(CAN Low) between these two.  If the differential voltage is around zero, the bus is in the Recessive state, logical 1.  If the voltage difference is (nominal) 2V, it's in the Dominant state, logical 0.

The other thing to know is that the bus is driven only in the dominant state.  That is, when a node wants to send a logical 0, its transmitter pulls CAN High toward the positive supply and CAN low toward the negative. To send a logical 1, the bus is undriven, in this case the terminating resistors pull the CAN High and CAN Low voltages difference to zero.  This is why a CAN bus must have at least one terminating resistor between CAN High and CAN Low, even if it is very short and transmission line effects are not a concern.

Since the bus is undriven in the Recessive state, any node can drive it into the Dominant state and over-ride a logical 1 with a logical 0.  A transmitting node monitors the bus during the arbitration phase.  If it detects a Dominant state while sending Recessive, it assumes that another node is transmitting simultaneously and stops transmitting, deferring to the other node having higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

CAN bus idles when no device drives any current to bus. Termination resistors between CANH and CANL keep the potential between the wires at 0V. This is the recessive state.

If any one or multiple devices drive current to bus, the CANH is at higher voltage than CANL, and thus there is potential difference, and this is defined as the dominant state.

The current to CAN chips that drive the bus comes from power supply.

The wires may be biased with voltage so that both wires are at 2.5V when idle.

That's basically a differential version of open-collector bus, where in idle state a reaistor keeps bus voltage high, but any one or multiple devices can pull the voltage low to active state.